# JavaScript equivalent of PHP $array[$i][]

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, equivalent

I have a problem with the creation of a multidimensional array in JavaScript.

The PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
$matches = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 3);

foreach($matches as $match) {

     $levels[$match][] = $match;
}

print_r($levels);
?>
```

print_r of $levels:

```
levels[1][0] = 1
levels[2][0] = 2
levels[3][0] = 3
levels[4][0] = 4
levels[4][1] = 4
levels[4][2] = 4
levels[6][0] = 6
levels[6][1] = 6
levels[2][1] = 2
levels[3][1] = 3
```

I have a problem with the creation the same array in JavaScript.

```
<script>
var levels = [];

$([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 3]).each(function(key, value) {

     levels[value][] = value;
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me create the same array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't magically create an array if there is none. You have to create it yourself. So it would be something like

```
$([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 3]).each(function(key, value) {
    if (levels[value] == null) {
        levels[value] = [];
    }
    levels[value].push(value);
});
```

[Learn more about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Comment: Please use `===` instead of `==`. Better yet, `if(!levels[value])`

Comment: @JanDvorak: If I used `===` it would not work, since the condition would never be fulfilled. `x == null` is just a short form for `x === null || x === undefined`. But yeah, simply converting to a boolean would be fine as well here.

Comment: Sorry... Never seen people actually using `== null` for `x === null || x === undefined`. I guess it's a reason I shouldn't be doing it either.

Answer (score 2):

Felix's answer is good and readable, I just want to introduce you to a couple of useful idioms.

Unlike php, javascript `||` (boolean OR) operator, despite its name, doesn't return boolean, but rather the first non-falsy operand. So when you write

```
a = thing || otherThing
```

the result will be `otherThing` if `thing` is falsy (= `null, undefined, 0, empty string`). Therefore checks like this

```
if(!foo)
   foo = bar
```

can be written more concisely as

```
foo = foo || bar
```

If `foo` is truthy, it just assigns `foo` to `foo` (a no-op), otherwise, `foo` becomes `bar`.

Applied to your problem, this will look like this:

```
levels[value] = levels[value] || [];
levels[value].push(value);
```

If you want to shorten this even more, replace [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
levels[value] = (levels[value] || []).concat(value);
```

This is not necessarily more readable or efficient, just something worth knowing about.

Comment: A solution in honor of your answer: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 3].reduce(function (p, c) {
    (p[c] || (p[c] = [])).push(c); 
    return p;
}, []);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var levels = [];
var orgArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < orgArray.length; i++) {
    var value = orgArray[i];
    if (levels[value] === undefined)
        levels[value] = []
    levels[value].push(value);
}
//Print
for (var j = 0; j < levels.length; j++)
    if (levels[j])
        for (var k = 0; k < levels[j].length; k++)
            console.log("levels[" + j + "][" + k + "] = " + levels[j][k]);
```

It's a bit overkill but you will get the point I think.
Don't forget to check if your elements exists